# Largest number in a string [Java]

Tags: java, string

I've started quite interesting problem and would approve of some tips and hints to solve it.

Problem is: "Find the largest number in a string.". For example if I type
`String s = "123dja321kk12vas"` the program should output 321.

Comment: *Parse* all the possible numbers in the `String` and store them in two variables only: `current` and `max`. Keep the value of both only.

Comment: Would try that, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Split the string using a regex then loop through all elements, parse them to numbers and get the largest.

Since `String.split()` requires you to provide a regex that matches the delimiters, i.e. in your case everything between digits, use the regex `\D+`, i.e. "a sequence of at least one non-digit character". Note though that `\d` matches non-ASCII digits as well, hence `\D` won't match those, so if you only want to parse ASCII digits you should use `[^0-9]+`.

Rough example:

```
String[] elements = input.split("[^0-9]+");
for( String element : elements ) {
  //skip empty elements, see note
  if( element.isEmpty() ) { 
    continue; 
  }
  //parse and compare here
}
```

One note: `String.split()` will not remove empty elements at the beginning of the array (e.g. when your starts with a non-digit character) thus you'd need to skip empty elements in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I tried the code and there's only one thing that bothers me and it is that elements array's first element is empty.

Comment: @MiroslavLalev I already edited my answer ;)

Comment: haha, thanks for the fast and educational response :)

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 you could do

```
// split by non-digits trimming the leading non-digits.
long max = Stream.of(text.replaceAll("^\\D+","").split("\\D+"))
                 .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
                 .max().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: The power of streams :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a number, you do not need it. Thus, you could use an expression such as `\D+` together with the `split(String regex)` method. This should yield only numbers stored as an array of strings.

Once that you have a string array of numerical values, simply go over them, convert them to integers and compare them to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know java, but this is a possible algorithm:

1. Loop through string.
2. If the character is not a number, do nothing with it.
3. If the character is a number, keep going through loop until you hit a non-numeric.
4. save the number in a container.
5. repeat until end of loop.
6. loop through container to see which number is the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

**java code**

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Integer>num= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String str="143dja321kk5vas";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            sb.append(c);
            int value = Character.getNumericValue(c);
            num.add(value);

        } 
    }


    System.out.println(num);
    Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();
    hs.addAll(num);
    num.clear();
    num.addAll(hs);

    Collections.reverse(num);
    System.out.println(num);
    System.out.println(num.get(num.size()-1));

    String listString = "";

    for (Integer s : num)
    {
        listString += s ;
    }

    System.out.println(listString);
}
```